# Finding nested intervals?

Tags: real-analysis

I have an analysis final tonight and I'm realizing how terrible I am at questions asking about nested intervals, such as these examples about intersections:

$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} [−1/n, 0] = \{0\}$

$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (−1/n, 0) = \emptyset$

$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (−1/n, 2/n) = \{0\}$

$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} [1/n, (2n-1)/n] = \{1\}$

I really have no idea how to approach these questions, or how you would find these answers.  How do you know that $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (−1/n, 0)$ is empty?  I'd really appreciate an explanation of how to do these kinds of questions.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: After some more thought - are you just looking for the number that is contained in all of the nested intervals?  For example, for [-1/n, 0], you're taking the intersection of [-1,0], [-1/2, 0], [-1/3, 0] and so on.  So the only number contained in all of those is 0, since the rest eventually get eliminated as n goes to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, you know $1/n \longrightarrow 0$, so you would expect the intersection of these intervals to contain only $0$ if any point at all. Let us write a formal proof.

We know $0 \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} [-1/n,0]$ since $0\in[-1/n,0]$ for all $n$. Now suppose $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} [-1/n,0], x\neq0 $. Then we must have $x \in [-1/n, 0]$ for all $n$. In particular, $x \in [-1,0]$. But, if $x \neq 0$ then there is $m \in \mathbf{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{-x} < m.$ So, we have $x < -1/m < 0$. Thus, for any $n > m$ we have $x \notin [-1/n,0]$. Thus, $x \notin \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} [-1/n,0]$. So, we see that only $0 \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[-1/n,0]$. Thus, $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[-1/n,0] = \{0\}$.

This should give you an idea on how to write these proofs. Give them a try and come back if you have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

For the first equivalence you could argue:

$\{0\}$ banally belongs to each interval $[-\frac{1}{n},0]$ so it belongs to their intersection.

Suppose now that exist another element $-\epsilon$ with $\epsilon>0$ small as you want, then there will surelly exist $n$ such that $n>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ then $-\frac{1}{n}>-\epsilon$ so $\epsilon \notin [-\frac{1}{n},0]$  neither to  ${\bigcap}_{n}[-\frac{1}{n},0]$.

So no other element can belong to that intersection.